# PHP string matching

Tags: php, regex, fuzzy-logic

I have stuck in writing a PHP function that will match the 2 character. Here is the example. This My Array 1

```
$arr1 = array(
    "ABC" => 'c4',
    "A" => 'c1',
    "AC" => 'c2',
    "ACC" => 'c3',
    "aBC" => 'c5',
);
```

And this is Array 2

```
$arr2 = array('ACXMASD','aCXMASD','ACCXMASD','ABCDXMASD','ABXAAAAS');
```

Now What I need to find is the closes match in Keys of Array 1 and Values of Array 2

Considering ACXMASD:

Now while compairing it with my Array 1. I should AC as the closest Match and Not A or ACC

Similarly Considering ABXAAAAS. I should get "A" as the best match and not ABC.

In other words I want the Keys to be exactly match with the string.

I have tried this code which I have found from stackoverflow. But the problem with it is that is as follow.

My Function

```
function findClosestMatchingString($s) {

    $stringEditDistanceThreshold = 7;
    $arr2 = array(
                  "ABC" => 'c4',
                  "A" => 'c1',
                  "AC" => 'c2',
                  "ACC" => 'c3',
                  "aBC" => 'c5',
                  );
    $closestDistanceThusFar = $stringEditDistanceThreshold + 1;
    $closestMatchValue      = null;

    foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
        $editDistance = levenshtein($key, $s);
        echo "$editDistance <br/>";
        // exact match
        if ($editDistance == 0) {
            return $value;

            // best match thus far, update values to compare against/return
        } elseif ($editDistance < $closestDistanceThusFar) {
            $closestDistanceThusFar = $editDistance;
            $closestMatchValue[]     = $value;
        }
    }

    return $closestMatchValue; // possible to return null if threshold hasn't been met
}

$arr1 = array('ACXMASD','aCXMASD','ACCXMASD','ABCDXMASD','ABXAAAAS');
// do the mapping
print_r(findClosestMatchingString('ABXAAAAS'));
```

Now the problem is that print_r is returning c4. But I am expecting it to return c1 because that key is matching completely. the key with value c4 is ABC but my string has ABX.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you understand what Levenshtein distance is.

Comment: To change `A` to `ABXAAAAS` requires adding`BXAAAAS`, that's a distance of 7. To change `ABC` to `ABXAAAAS` requires replacing `C` with `X` and adding `AAAAS`, that's a distance of only 6.

Comment: I see. Let me try playing with that. Do you think  I am in right direction. I mean do I really need to use Levenshtein distance or this can be done through some other ways in PHP(If you understood what I am after). Thanks again

Comment: I don't think you should be using Levenshtein. I think you should just be using `strpos()` and choosing the longest key that matches.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to find the longest substring from the beginning of the setting value in question that matches one of the keys.  Would this be correct?

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you were looking for:

```
<?php 
$arr1 = array('ACXMASD','aCXMASD','ACCXMASD','ABCDXMASD','ABXAAAAS');

$arr2 = array(
        "ABC" => 'c4',
        "A" => 'c1',
        "AC" => 'c2',
        "ACC" => 'c3',
        "aBC" => 'c5',
);

krsort($arr2);

foreach($arr1 as $val1)
{
    echo "<br /> Searching for $val1";
    foreach($arr2 as $var => $val2)
    {
        if(strpos($val1, $var) !== false)
        {
            echo "<br />Best Case for " . $val1 . " is " . $val2 . " " . $var . " <br />";
            break;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Hardly the "best case"

Comment: I just follow what Barmar said. I used strpos and then I find the longest string.

$a = "ACCXMASD";
 $arr2 = array(
  "ACC" => 'c3',
  "ABC" => 'c4',
  "AC" => 'c2',
  "aBC" => 'c5',
  "A" => 'c1',
 );
 
 foreach($arr2 as $key => $v){
  if(strpos($a, $key) === 0){
   $m[] = $key;
  }
 }

print_r($m);